# jQuery Mobile Select Menu opened as dialog

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-mobile

I've a 'pagebeforeshow' handler that clears the value of my text boxes and select menus.

```
$("#addSchedulePage").live("pagebeforeshow", function(event){
    $("#message", $("#addSchedulePage")).html("");//clear messagebox
    $("#message", $("#addSchedulePage")).hide();//hide messagebox
    $("#startDate", $("#addSchedulePage")).val("");
    $("#time", $("#addSchedulePage")).val("");

   var lstAppliance = $("#lstAppliance", $("#addSchedulePage"));
    var lstScheduleTaskType = $("#lstScheduleTaskType", $("#addSchedulePage"));
    lstAppliance[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    lstScheduleTaskType[0].selectedIndex = 0;

    $("#lstAppliance", $("#addSchedulePage")).selectmenu('refresh');
    $("#lstScheduleTaskType", $("#addSchedulePage")).selectmenu('refresh');

});
```

Here's the problem. When my select menus options gets too long jqm automatically open a new dialog instead of dropping down the list when i click on it and causing the event to be triggered again when i select a options from the select menu. 
Is there a workaround or a away to stop the event from triggering?

Comment: what version of jQM are you using?

Comment: using the nightly build.

Comment: until the official release a4.1 is only supported as the nightly builds change (nightly). I think the beta release is coming very soon though

Comment: See the following solution for the same issue:

[this might help][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047301/jquery-mobile-issue-with-long-select-multiple-option-and-data-native-menu-false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. after sitting down and think through the flow of my program i managed to solve this by changing the way i handle things.

This is the flow of the program.
schedulePage (click on add button) --> addSchedulePage (clicked on the select menu) --> Dialog with all available options.

schedulePage --> addSchedulePage ('pagebeforeshow' fired)

Select menu dialog --> addSchedulePage ('pagebeforeshow' fired) -- all my values is cleared after i select the options that i want from my select menu.

If you notice in my question i wanted to clear the value when the event 'pagebeforeshow' is fired.
So instead of clearing values when the page is shown, i cleared the value when i clicked on the 'add button' in schedulePage. This works because when i closed the addSchedulePage, jquerymobile simply hide it and it's still in the DOM.

I'm not sure if this's the correct way to do things but it definitely solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

My answer won't help you for your problem, but you can simplify your code :

```
$("#addSchedulePage").live("pagebeforeshow", function(event){
    $("#message", this).html("").hide(); //clear and hide messagebox
    $("#startDate", this).val("");
    $("#time", this).val("");

    var lstAppliance = $("#lstAppliance", this);
    var lstScheduleTaskType = $("#lstScheduleTaskType", this);
    lstAppliance[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    lstScheduleTaskType[0].selectedIndex = 0;

    lstAppliance.selectmenu('refresh');
    lstScheduleTaskType.selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

I have :

- used `this` which reffers to
  `$("#addSchedulePage")`.
- chained `.html()` and `.hide()`
- used your variables `lstAppliance`
  and `lstScheduleTaskType`

Comment: ahh.. thanks. I've no idea i can use the 'this' keyword to specify the context. I also have a habit of specifying the context as i do not want buttons etc to have conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it.
This might solve it for you as well:

[Stackoverflow link to issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047301/jquery-mobile-issue-with-long-select-multiple-option-and-data-native-menu-false)

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of the one you linked to?  If so, flag it as such.